# How to block pull request in kafka consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

When there is not data in broker to fetch, consumer remains in tight loop until data arrives. Therefore I want to find a way to tell the consumer to wait until broker has some data. I'm using Kafka 0.9 java client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically Kafka is Pull based client, it will keep querying the server to figure out if there are new messages, either you can have higher poll interval or you could use the concept of fetch.max.wait.ms and fetch.min.bytes, This is what documentation says about fetch.min.bytes - The minimum amount of data the server should return for a fetch request. If insufficient data is available the request will wait for that much data to accumulate before answering the request.

Comment: Using this properties fetch.min.bytes and fetch.max.wait.ms means that consumer must know what minimum amount of bytes will be consumed and time to wait. But I was looking something that block consumer until data arrives but broker would notify consumer. However as is pull-based system those properties seems to be appropiate in this case